# How to upload multiple different file types (pdf, xls, png) from android to node server

Tags: android, android-networking

Is there any library to upload different type of files to `NodeJS` server back-end.

I need to send following three different types of files

1. *.png
2. *.xls
3. *.pdf

I have solution for same files sending to backend. But how to do with different files?

Comment: Let's know till now what you have done?

Comment: Till now i done multiple photo upload from android to Node JS. But i don't have idea for how to upload different types of files from android. That functionality like gmail file attachment.

Comment: Okay for selecting multiple images what are you doing ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
String[] mimeTypes =
        {"application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
         "application/pdf",
         "image/*"};

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
    if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    }
} else {
    String mimeTypesStr = "";
    for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
        mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
    }
    intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
}
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"), REQUEST_CODE_DOC);
```